# From Dictionary select only specified keys using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like this

```
object tst = folderItems.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new {
   i.File.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues,
   i.File.UniqueId
});
```

in this code `File.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues` is a dictionary. While constructing this object I want to select only few items from this dictionary. And I have tried something like this

```
object tst = folderItems.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new {
    i.File.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues.Where(x=>x.Key=="mykey"),
    i.File.UniqueId
});
```

But this resulted in a compile time error. How can I achieve this?

Error

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: what is the compile time error?

Comment: I guess, the class and example data in the post will help to understand the issue better

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Error added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it simply says that for your anonymous class you should provide a name:

```
object tst = folderItems.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new {
                FieldValues = i.File.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues.Where(x=>x.Key=="mykey"),
                i.File.UniqueId
            });
```

Note that if you don't give it a name (like the second property), the property name (`UniqueId` in this cause will be used), this you know as you have used it like that, however if it is not a property and it's a method, you should give it a name yourself, for example you'll get an error if you don't give a name for `something.Count()` and it should be `Count = something.Count()`
The above code should solve your problem. also consider adding ToList(), ...

```
.Where(x=>x.Key=="mykey").ToList()
```